# Round-Tripping Visual Studio projects but always using the "latest" Platform Toolset?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, multitargeting

[As described](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/24/stuck-on-an-older-toolset-version-move-to-visual-studio-2015-without-upgrading-your-toolset/):

> ... Visual Studio supports native
>   multi-targeting and round-tripping. And we definitely want to shine
>   more light on it:
>
> Native multi-targeting is the ability of the latest IDE to build using
>   toolsets installed by previous versions of Visual Studio (VS 2008 and
>   up).
>
> Round-tripping is the ability of the latest IDE to load projects
>   created by a previous IDE version without making any changes to the
>   project assets (VS 2010 projects and up), thus allowing it to load
>   back in the previous IDE too.

What I'm unclear about is whether a project can be configured so that it will load without conversion in VS-2015 - so it still can be used with VS-2010 - but it should use the VS-2015 (`v140`) platform toolset in VS-2015 and the `v100` one when loaded in VS-2010.

Since by default a project doesn't contain the `<PlatformToolset>` setting it should work, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my experience goes so far: **yes**, simply omitting `<PlatformToolset>` from the project file will result in Visual Studio simply using *its* version's default.